# How to index dynamic urls in sharepoint

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

I have a page in SharePoint with a search results webpart, for example results.aspx

And I also have a webpart that takes a dynamic parameter from the url and shows the results.

For example:

- result.aspx?person=Luis
- result.aspx?person=Diego
- result.aspx?person=Andres
- result.aspx?person=Pedro

As you can see its one page with hundreds of different parameters. How can I make Google to index all those page results?

This is Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise.

Comment: do you want google to index your page or you want sharepoint search index these pages?

Comment: Is this an externally facing public website?

Comment: yes its a public website